# Comb Sort Not Working In C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm having problems with trying to code a comb sort in c++. I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, it just doesn't sort the list.

```
 void comb()
{
    int gap = 9;
    int temp;
    double shrink = 1.3;
    bool swapped;
    do
    {
        gap = int (gap/shrink);
        if (gap < 1)
        {
            gap = 1;
        }
        swapped = false;
        for (i = 0; (i + gap) <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[i + gap])
            {
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + gap];
                list[i + gap] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        arrayout();
    }
    while ((gap > 1) & (swapped == true));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wouldn't hard code the 9 and 10.

Second, I assume `arrayout()` prints the array? You're doing that inside the loop, before it's sorted. Move it to the end, after the loop.

Third, the AND operator is `&&` not `&`.  The `&` is a bitwise and - not what you want.

Otherwise, it looks ok.

Comment: +1  Good catch on the & operator.  In addition to the hard coding of those values, I kind of wonder if `list` is an array defined as `list[10]`.  If so, then the for loop going up to <= 10 is wrong.  It should probably be strictly less (`< 10`).

Answer (score 0):

So imagine the first time through with an array `[1, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 9]`.
`a[0] < a[9]`, so it does not get swapped.

Now you get to your `while` test:  `gap >1` but `swapped` is false. so you exit.

You will have the same problem if all the items at any gap size are already in order.
You need to get all the way down to gap size 1 before you start testing `swapped`.

*(@dsa42 is right, it should be `&&`, but that doesn't change the logic error.)*

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm don't think that this is correct.  swapped being false won't make it exit.  Gap has to be <= 1 AND swapped has to be false - both must be true to exit.

See the code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort

Comment: I don't agree: The condition as written is `while ((gap > 1) && (swapped == true));`.  So when `swapped` is `false`, the whole condition is false, and the loop exits regardless of gap size.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The condition should be changed to


' until (gap = 1 && swapped = false) '